# setTimeout to detect changes in a text field

Tags: javascript, iframe, textarea

I wonder why the following sample code doesn't work properly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            textarea, iframe {
                display:block;
                width:300px;
                height:100px;
                margin:3px;
                padding:3px;
                border:1px solid #CCC;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <textarea id="field" onfocus="getFocus();" onblur="loseFocus();">This is some text.</textarea>
        <iframe name="target"></iframe>
        <script>
            var textarea = document.getElementById('field');
            var iframe = window.target.document;

            function displayResult() {
                if (textarea.value) {
                    iframe.open();
                    iframe.write(textarea.value);
                    iframe.close();
                }
                window.setTimeout(displayResult, 10);
            }

            function getFocus() {
                if (textarea.value == textarea.defaultValue) {
                    textarea.value = '';
                }
            }

            function loseFocus() {
                if (textarea.value == '') {
                    textarea.value = textarea.defaultValue;
                }
            }
            displayResult();
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RainLover/4ksMR/

The iframe content is supposed to get updated in real time -- as soon as the textarea content changes by keyboard or mouse. This approach is an alternative to the `oninput` event. But since `oninput` isn't well-supported across different browsers I decided to create a timer to compare the current text field value with its value in 10 milliseconds before.

Comment: What is it supposed to do that it doesn't do?  I see a textarea whose contents get written into the iframe every 10ms (100x / sec, insanely often). From my reading of the code, that looks to be exactly what it is supposed to do.

Comment: we're going to need more information than "doesn't work properly". what are you trying to do? what is it doing instead?

Comment: It's supposed to dynamically update the iframe and write the textarea content value into it.

Comment: @RainLover that's what it does. It works perfectly in Chrome & FF.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not true.

Comment: Ok what do you see it doing?  I see it reflect exactly what is typed into the textarea in the iframe in real time.

Comment: Please try adding and removing some code/text using both mouse and keyboard.

Comment: Ok - that works too.  I can type in it and cut/paste into it and it is all reflected in the iframe, also drag and drop.

Comment: Just updated my question for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Let me give an example: enter a sentence into the text field. Then select/highlight it. Now press the 'Delete' button on your keyboard. You won't see the same thing on the iframe"*

The problem is this line:

```
if (textarea.value) {
```

If `textarea` is blank, i.e., the `.value` is an empty string, then the if condition is falsy and the copy to the iframe doesn't happen. Just remove the `if`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4ksMR/1/

(Note that this was the *only* case where I was able to duplicate your problem that changes were not reflected in the iframe.)

Comment: You've earned the [Mother Theresa] badge for sticking this out and managing to figure out what the OP expects.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Thanks for the answer, but how can I set it up to rewrite content to the iframe _only if_ there's a change in the textarea content, something like this: `if (textarea.value != textarea.value.10ms.ago)`?

Comment: `if(textarea.value!=prevValue) { prevValue=textarea.value; /*and update iframe*/ }`, where `prevValue` should be declared outside your function.

Answer (score 0):

why are you "polling" for changes? just append a keyup-handler (which notifies you when someone has typed into your textarea-field)

```
textarea.onkeyup = function() {
    // do whatever you want to do here
}
```

Comment: ...and handlers for non-keyboard based editing with cut and paste, and drag'n'drop...

Comment: then use the onkeyup and onblur event together. polling for changes is just an ugly solution

Answer (score 0):

reconsider your implementation, here is simple sample with jquery, but surely it might be done on any other lib or even core JS

http://jsbin.com/oraxeb/1

Just think about such improvements like:

1. not every keyUp should works, for example Ctrl or arrows or shift or bunch or others, that's will improve performance
2. initial default text - quite simple
3. probably something else)